# Password change HELLLPPP

Tags: 12.04, password

I can't modify my password, but i have nothing set. 
I have gDebi (no pass asking).
who can help me??
Please...
I have Ubuntu 12.04
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh

Answer (score 1):

Open up a terminal and run the command `passwd`. It should prompt you for your current password and then let you enter a new password. (If you do not have a password set it will just prompt you for a new password.)